# Tensorflow hub urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

Tags: python, tensorflow-hub

I use Tensorflow hub to run an object detection on kaggle kernel and it`s good.
But when I run the code in local IDE, it will raise an error below:
urllib.error.URLError: 
How can I solve it ?

'''python

model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/faster_rcnn/openimages_v4/inception_resnet_v2/1"

'''

Comment: Hi Shengzf, can you please share the details of your Local IDE. Also, can you please paste the full stack trace of the error. Also, we can help if you can share the code you used (only if it can be), so that we can try reproducing that error. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing this is some sort of local network problem (firewall? ISP not working?) Please check your firewall and ISP and see if they are in order. Thanks!